# Force applied by a spring stretched to a different direction

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, spring

This may be a bit basic but I am unsure of the answer.
Assume the following simple setup: a spring with a spring constant **k** and of length **L**, connected to mass **m**.
[image: Diagram]

What is the force applied by the spring on the mass if the mass is pulled along the Y axis, say by distance **d**?(The displacement is entirely on the Y axis)

Assuming **d << L** can it be simply broken down as if the string was vertical (**F=-kd**)?

Answers describing oscillations instead of the force would be just as welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

Where in one dimension you would have $F=-kx$, you now have $\mathbf{F}=-k\mathbf{x}$ (assuming a simple Hookean spring) with $\mathbf{x}$ being the distance vector from the mass to the pivot of the spring.

Comment: I don't think that can be done. A spring is _one dimensional_, just think, you wouldn't feel the same force when its pulled in the $y$ direction

Comment: If by pivot you mean the point of attachment to the wall then it doesn't hold to simplification to one dimension, as Hook's law talks about displacement vector and not actual distance.
If you are referring to the resting point of the mass then if the displacement is on the y axis then the force would also be entirely on the y axis? Not entirely sure this add up for me, as displacing on the y axis also increases the length of the spring suggesting a force should exist along the vector between the wall and the mass.. What am I missing?

Comment: sigh. this gets tedious is really basic stuff:  with a finite resting length it would be something like $\mathbf{F}=-k (|\mathbf{x}|-l_0) \hat{\mathbf{x}}$  where the hat denots a unit vector. @TheGhostOfPerdition not sure what you want to say

Comment: I think that $F=-kx$n is only applicable in the $x$ direction, generalising it to $\mathbf F=-k\mathbf x$, wouldnt be right, for a spring along $x$ axis stretching it in $y$ direction how are you sure that the y component of $F$ varies as $-ky$?

Comment: If L is the original length of the spring and the end to the right is displaced a distance d in the y direction, using the Pythagorean theorem, what is the new length of the spring?  What is the change in length?

Answer (score 0):

Let me assume(correct me if I am wrong) that the displacement is purely in the y-direction, starting from the free state of the spring. In such a case, the length of the spring can be calculated using the Pythagoras theorem(say l'). The change in length of the spring would now be l' - l( where l is the free length of the spring ). The spring force acting on the mass would be F = -k(l' - l).

Comment: If you don't get the Pythagoras Theorem part, let me know and I'll post a picture for your understanding!

Comment: Your assumption is correct, I meant the displacement is solely on the Y axis. And would the direction of the force be entirely on the Y axis or would it be toward the wall, to the point where the string is attached?

Comment: Nope, the force would be in the direction leading from the mass to the point on the wall where it is attached!